# array data type manipulation

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have an array of arrays of objects.
so it looks something like
`[[{}{}],[{}{}{}],[{}{}], [{}{}{}{}]]`...etc
I need to loop through each object in this array. Problem is that would require a `nested for loop`, which isn't bad but I was wondering if there is any way I could use the spread operator when I'm putting it in the original array.
`outerArray.push(...innerArray)`, something along the lines of that. That didn't work but is there something similar?

Comment: Use `[].concat(...outerArray)`

Comment: @MohammadUsman that's a shallow flat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Array.prototype.flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) to convert a nested array, into a flattened array

```
var arr1 = [1, 2, [3, 4]];
arr1.flat(); 
// [1, 2, 3, 4]

var arr2 = [1, 2, [3, 4, [5, 6]]];
arr2.flat();
// [1, 2, 3, 4, [5, 6]]

var arr3 = [1, 2, [3, 4, [5, 6]]];
arr3.flat(2);
// [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

For older browsers, you can refer to [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865025/merge-flatten-an-array-of-arrays-in-javascript)

Comment: That's probably how I would've done it, clean, simple & straight to the point.

Comment: great answer! i might stick with nested loops but this works.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding another option here that doesn't require passing the depth in:

```
const deepFlatten = arr =>
  [].concat(...arr.map(v => (Array.isArray(v) ? deepFlatten(v) : v)))
```

call with `deepFlatten(outerArray)`